# What are the achievements in Kittens game, and how can one get them?

Tags: achievements, kittens-game

While playing Kittens game, players can access a tab labelled "achievements". When clicked on, shows a list of several fields, each containing a plain "???".
I managed to get only a single one of the achievements completed: the one for 3 kittens starving to death.

How are all the achievements named, and how to get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [list of achievements](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Achievements) and how to get them can be reviewed on the Kittens Game wiki.

> #### Unicorn Conspiracy
>
> Find one unicorn (from hunting or random event in [Iron Will](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Iron+Will))
>
> #### Uniception
>
> Find one unicorn tear (build a ziggurat, research theology, obtain Faith, and sacrifice unicorns)
>
> #### Sins of a Solar Empire
>
> Find one alicorn (requires [Sky Palace](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Religion#Sky_Palace))
>
> #### Anachronox
>
> Find one time crystal (sacrifice alicorns or trade with Leviathans)
>
> #### Dead Space
>
> Find one necrocorn (requires Marker)
>
> #### Iron Will
>
> Build a mine without ever buying housing in current game
>
> #### Uberkatzchen
>
> Build a warehouse without ever buying housing in current game
>
> #### One Hundred Years of Solitude
>
> Build a steamworks without ever buying housing in current game
>
> #### Virgin Soil Upturned
>
> Build 45 pastures without ever buying housing in current game
>
> #### Atlas Unmeowed
>
> Build a magneto without ever buying housing in current game
>
> #### Meow Meow Revolution
>
> Build a factory without ever buying housing in current game
>
> #### Space Oddity
>
> Research Moon Mission without ever buying housing in current game (Regular Version)
>   Research Moon Mission without ever buying housing in current game with less than 10 paragon (Insane Version, has Star)
>
> #### Jupiter Ascending
>
> Complete the Orbital Launch mission before the end of year 1
>
> #### Shadow Of The Colossus
>
> With exactly one kitten in the current game, build a Ziggurat
>
> #### Sun God
>
> Accumulate 696,342 faith
>
> #### Heart Of Darkness
>
> Have more than one zebra
>
> #### Winter Is Coming
>
> Kill 10 kittens in current game
>
> #### You Monster
>
> Kill 100 kittens in current game
>
> #### Super Unethical Climax
>
> Click on the "Gather Catnip" button 2,500 times with no more than 2.5 seconds passing between each click having had at least one "extra" kitten (kittens > 0) at some point in the current game
>
> #### Lotus Eater Machine
>
> Obtain at least 1 karma by resetting game
>
> #### Serenity
>
> Have 50 kittens with none dying in current game
>
> #### Utopia Project
>
> Have more than 35 kittens and a happiness score of 150% or greater. (Regular Version)
>   Have more than 35 kittens and a happiness score of 500% or greater. (Insane Version, has Star)
>
> #### Cathammer 40K
>
> Have 40,000 total years played (It's in [Stats](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Stats)!). (Regular Version)
>   Get to game year 40,000. (Insane Version, has Star) (Please note that years gained by skipping ahead by shattering time crystals DOES NOT COUNT!)
>
> #### Limitless Clicker
>
> Have clicked 100,000 times (It's in [Stats](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Stats)!)
>   Have clicked 1,000,000 times (Insane Version, has Star)

Comment: Earning "Super Unethical Climax"  seems to prevent you from getting any other achievements or earning Karma or Paragon points in that run.

Comment: A new one "System Shock"  Try and sell an AI core.   Not sure what other restrictions are around this.